# Fetching all user details from mongodb returns null

Tags: node.js, mongodb, authentication, jwt

get user details by id

```
router.get("/user", auth, async (req, res) => {
  let id = req.user_id;
  userControllers
    .userById(id)
    .then((user) => res.status(200).json(user))
    .catch((err) => res.status(404).json(err));
});

module.exports = router;
```

auth.js

```
const jwt = require("jsonwebtoken");

module.exports = (req, res, next) => {
  const token = req.headers.authorization.split(" ")[1];
  if (!token) {
    res.status(401).send("undefined Token!!");
  }
  try {
    const decodedToken = jwt.verify(token, "secretToken");
    req.userId = decodedToken.userId;
    next();
  } catch (error) {
    res.status(400).send("invalid token!");
    console.log(error);
  }
};
```

i get an undefined when i want to show user details from mongodb,
can someone show me what i do wrong please?

Comment: What is the mongo query you use to get all user details?

Comment: User.findOne({ email: email });